# MySQL DELETE QUERY ERROR

Tags: mysql

Please help to correct the following mysql query,

It is throwing error like

> 'operand should contain one column'

```
delete from l0_clarabridge_s.incr_sentence_class_xref where   incr_sentence_class_xref.document_id NOT IN (
select *
from l0_clarabridge_s.incr_sentence_class_xref
join l0_clarabridge_s.incr_document
on incr_sentence_class_xref.document_id = incr_document.document_id);
```

Comment: Use `SELECT id_column....` instead of  `SELECT * .....`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operand Should Contain 1 Column - MySQL NOT IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318208/operand-should-contain-1-column-mysql-not-in)

Comment: Even after adding document_id,  select * from l0_clarabridge_s.incr_sentence_class_xref where document_id NOT IN (
select x.document_id
from l0_clarabridge_s.incr_sentence_class_xref x
join l0_clarabridge_s.incr_document d
on x.document_id = d.document_id);

Comment: It is throwing error like 'Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'incr_sentence_class_xref' for update in FROM clause'

Comment: Please **edit** and update your question rather than posting in comments,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the document_id to your select:

```
delete from l0_clarabridge_s.incr_sentence_class_xref where   incr_sentence_class_xref.document_id NOT IN (
select incr_sentence_class_xref.document_id
from l0_clarabridge_s.incr_sentence_class_xref
join l0_clarabridge_s.incr_document
on incr_sentence_class_xref.document_id = incr_document.document_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing your `WHERE` statement to two columns instead of one, try the following:

```
DELETE FROM l0_clarabridge_s.incr_sentence_class_xref WHERE   incr_sentence_class_xref.document_id NOT IN (
SELECT [insert your ID column name here]
FROM l0_clarabridge_s.incr_sentence_class_xref
JOIN l0_clarabridge_s.incr_document
ON incr_sentence_class_xref.document_id = incr_document.document_id);
```